# Totally remove an Extension Custom Protocol with URI

Tags: c#, powershell, uwp

I have an UWP application which handles URI launches.

*Package.manifest*

```
<Extensions>
  <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol">
    <uap:Protocol Name="my.app">
      <uap:DisplayName>My UWP App</uap:DisplayName>
    </uap:Protocol>
  </uap:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

It works fine, but when I uninstall my app, the custom protocol remains activated (but it tells me "incorrect value in registry"). 
Also, I use some C# (in a WPF app) to check if my app is ready to handles URI launches.

```
public static bool IsAppReady()
{
    using (var classKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, RegistryView.Registry64))
    {
        return classKey.OpenSubKey("my.app") != null;
    }
}
```

That fact is that this code returns true even after the app is uninstalled. I can also find remanings key named "my.app" in the registry.
Is there a way to totally delete a custom protocol, by code or powershell ?

Comment: When I added the custom protocol and uninstalled it, the protocol indeed existed in the registry. But I'm not sure why it still existed in it and how to totally delete a custom protocol. I'll continue to try it.

Comment: I have asked the team about it, and they said it is by design. The way the registry layout works is that apps must collaborate and agree on these reg-keys. For example, two apps that handle PDF both require that the HKCR\.pdf key exists. Uninstalling one of those apps must not remove that key, or it would break the .pdf file-type-association for the remaining app. Same thing for protocols.